# How to make Excel stay in one Ribbon menu rather than go back to Home each time?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am trying to draw some shapes and going through trial and error. I goto "Insert" menu on the ribbon. I select a shape under "Illustrations" in the "Insert" menu and put a shape onto the spreadsheet work area. This causes Excel to enter a "Shape Format". When I deselect the shape, it goes back to the "Home" menu in the ribbon. I thus have to select the "Insert" menu each time after putting a shape onto Excel work area and deselecting it once I am done.

Is there a way to cause Excel to remain stuck in the "Insert" menu for some time rather than goto "Home" menu every time? This is very annoying.

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, I sugget you add the Shape feature onto Qucik Access Toolbar.

Go to File > Options > Quick Access Toolbar > Add Shapes feature.

[image]

Then you could find "Shapes" on Qucik Access Toolbar directly. If you don’t draw shapes later, you may cancel it on Quick Access Toolbar.

[image]